# Algorithm to generate water flow map, given a terrain

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

I've posted the [same question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/158017/1087) at GameDev Stack Exchange, but unfortunately I am not getting any response. So I am going to post ( and reword) it here. Hopefully I can get an answer!

I have a terrain ( in the form of mesh/element), and I want to indicate how the water flows in the terrain, subjected to gravity force and the terrain condition ( of course).

A crude way of doing this is to take every single mesh element, then draw the water flow direction from the highest point to the lowest, but I think this will result in a lot of ugly arrows that although can roughly point towards the correct directions, but really don't look nice when view as a whole.

Is there an algorithm, or even better, an existing code implementation ( in the form of well-documented APIs with Windows DLLs, or open source soure code), that allows me to generate the water "flow map" in an elegant, intuitive, look-nice way?

Comment: Another option is https://github.com/TUM-I5/SWE/wiki .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a well-studied problem in geomorphological and hydrological modeling, as well as the fields of geomorphometry and terrain analysis.

For visualization, [flow accumulation](https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flow_accumulation.html) is usually calculated. If every element of your terrain is taken as contributing a value of 1 to the flow, then flow accumulation is the sum of all the flow that passes through a given element. A depiction of this for a landscape might look like this:

[image: Flow accumulation]

There are several different [flow routing methods](https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/flow_metrics.html). The one you describe is known as D8. A few additional ones are depicted below.

[image: Different flow routing methods]

Algorithms for performing the above, along with citations to appropriate references, are available in my library, [RichDEM](https://richdem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

Comment: Looks impressive, but what does the legend actually stand for?

Comment: In this case, number of upstream cells or portion thereof.

Comment: So it would appear that the RED area is the lower ground and BLUE is the upper ground, based on the legend ( shouldn't it be the other way round to conform to the normal topography legend usage)?

Comment: That's correct. Red has a higher flow accumulation (more upstream cells) so its value is higher.

Comment: Interesting! Gotta check it out!

Answer (score 0):

There is one program, called IBER, that fits into your request:
http://www.iberaula.es/space/53/modules

You can download it for free here:
http://www.iberaula.es/space/54/downloads

Comment: Any specific module that I can use? Also, there seems to be no source code, nor a DLL that I can call?

Comment: I have never used this code before... Only I kew about its existence. You can also programm the Shallow Waters equations by your own...